# error: two or more data types in declaration of main?

Tags: c++, function, if-statement, while-loop, declaration

Very new to coding, so please be understanding ;)

I'm basically trying to make a calculator using the `while` loop, and `if` statements.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int x = 1;
int number;
int total = 0;
int amt = 1;
int a;
int b;
int c;
int d;
string ans;

class OperateClass
```

I get the error: two or more data types in declaration of 'main'

Please explain what this means/how to fix it.

I was also wondering if I need to make a new object for each function (Add, subtract, multiply, and divide)

Please help!

```
int main()
{

    cout << "Do you want to add, subtract, multiply or divide? I want to : " << endl;
    cin >> ans;

    if(ans == "add"){
        OperateClass opOper;
        opOper.add();

    }else{

        if(ans == "subtract"){
            OperateClass opOper
            opOper.subtract();
                }

    }else{

        if(ans == "multiply"){
            OperateClass opOper
            opOper.multiply();
        }

    }else{

        if(ans == "divide"){
            OperateClass opOper
            opOper.divide();

        }
    }

}

class OperateClass{
    public:
        int add(){
            while(x <= 3){
                cout << "Enter a number to use to add: " << endl;
                cin >> a;
                total = total + a;
                x++;
                amt++;
            }
        }

        int subtract(){
            while(x <= 3){
                cout << "Enter a number to use to add: " << endl;
                cin >> b;
                total = total - b;
                x++;
                amt++;
            }
        }

        int multiply(){
            while(x <= 3){
                cout << "Enter a number to use to add: " << endl;
                cin >> c;
                total = total * c;
                x++;
                amt++;
            }
        }

        int divide(){
            while(x <= 3){
                cout << "Enter a number to use to add: " << endl;
                cin >> d;
                total = total / d;
                x++;
                amt++;
            }
        }
}

int print(){
    cout << "Your total is: " << total << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you should use if-else if-else or switch. what you are doing now is confusing. difficult to find open and close brace.

Comment: Those global variables all over the place are really not a good idea.

Comment: In "if(ans == "subtract"/"multiply"/"divide")" 
you forget ";" after "Operate Class opOper"

Comment: Alright, I'm no longer getting the semicolon errors

Comment: Now I'm getting error: aggregate 'OperateClass opOper' has incomplete type and cannot be defined. How would this be corrected?

Comment: @Bucky763, Just kill the `class OperateClass;` and move the whole class there instead.

Comment: The usual way to write an `if` / `else if` / sequence is to treat the "else if" as if it were a single word. I can't format it correctly in a comment, but [this gist](https://gist.github.com/3126587) shows the more traditional way to do this. (Some languages even have `elsif` or `elseif` as a keyword; C++ doesn't.)

Comment: A switch would work well here too.

Comment: Ok I moved the Class definition before the main. The program runs now!

Comment: Now im wondering how to get `cout << "Your total is: " << total;` to run

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of that code is valid. You begin a class definition with `class OperateClass`, but never end it and run right into `main`.  A (simplified) class definition takes the form of:

```
class [name] {

};  // semi-colon terminates definition

// so...

class OperateClass {

};
```

Next, you declare `main`... but it leads to an `else` branch (?).

```
int main()
{

    cout << "Do you want to add, subtract, multiply or divide? I want to : " << endl;
    cin >> ans;

    if(ans == "add"){
    OperateClass opOper;
    opOper.add();

}else{  // what is this?
```

Functions must also terminate via their closing brace, i.e.,

```
int main() {

}  // function is over!
```

Now it looks like those may just be copy/paste errors.  If that's the case then you probably just forgot the semi-colon at the end of the class definition.

Comment: There's a hidden `if`. It's there, though.

Comment: @chris: Yeah that's why I added that last bit on.  I think a missing semi-colon is probably the issue and this was just a bad copy/paste job.

Comment: Alright. I'm going to edit the original code and add the semicolons.

Comment: @Bucky763: Please don't do that. With the code corrected, the question no longer makes sense. I'll roll back the edit for you.

Comment: Well I think it's been determined now that the problem was semicolons, which are in here among other things. Upvote for ya.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following program:

```
class C

int main() {

}

class C {

}

void someFunc(){}
```

This is basically your program boiled down to the necessities. Here are the errors:

```
error: two or more data types in declaration of 'main'
error: expected ';' after class definition
```

Here's the corrected code:

```
class C; //<--semicolon in forward declaration

int main() {

}

class C {

}; //<--semicolon after class definition

void someFunc(){}
```

Comment: Now I'm getting the _error: aggregate 'OperateClass opOper' has incomplete type and cannot be defined_

Comment: Just kill the class OperateClass; and move the whole class there instead.

Comment: Moving the class def before main got the program to run!

Comment: The only thing is, it wont run this function I added               `void print(){
    cout << "Your total is: " << total << endl;

}`

Comment: @Bucky763, A new question completely is more suited for further problems, but as a random guess, did you ever call it?

Comment: Ill make a new question. Thanks. And can you give an example of calling it?

Comment: I think I forgot that. Adding it to main should be fine?

Comment: @Bucky763, Wherever you want the printing to occur.

Answer (score 1):

Lets make a slight modification of your code so that your syntax is right.

```
int main()
{

    cout << "Do you want to add, subtract, multiply or divide? I want to : " << endl;
    cin >> ans;

    if(ans == "add"){
    OperateClass opOper;
    opOper.add();
        }

else if (ans == "subtract"){
    OperateClass opOper;
    opOper.subtract();
        }

else if (ans == "multiply"){
    OperateClass opOper;
    opOper.multiply();
        }

else if(ans == "divide"){
    OperateClass opOper;
    opOper.divide();

        }
else {} 

} //end of main
```

Your class variable declaration statement "OperateClass opOper" also repeats in each case, you could also just write that statement outside your if-else conditions to avoid repetition since that statement is true regardless of any case.